# ByteArrayBody cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I was trying to send byte array image to server

and I used :

```
  MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                //Set Data and Content-type header for the image
                entity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(ba, "image/jpeg", "file"));
                postRequest.setEntity(entity);
```

and I have this error

"ByteArrayBody cannot be resolved to a type"

and I imported to my project
 all httpmime, httpclient and httpcore jars !!

I don't know what else to do 
thanks in advance.

Comment: did you added jars to buildpath

Comment: yes I did I added them and still the same error

Comment: which version httpmime jar you are using?

Comment: you mean httpmime 4.0.1.jar?

Comment: yes ...... httpmime 4.0.1.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `httpmime 4.0 jar` then it shows error `ByteArrayBody cannot be resolved to a type.`

Need to replace with `httpmime 4.1 or later versions` then it works fine.

`ByteArrayBody` is introduced from `httpmime 4.1.jar onwards`.

for more refer httpmime [4.0](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime40sourcesjar.htm) and [4.1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime41sourcesjar.htm)